# How to load the project into Github

Tags: git, github, commit

When I load my project into Github, it writes me "Commit is failed". I use bower and nodeJS, and I think that problems is about it, but I need to download these catalogs. What I need to do, or may be it can be done in another way?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These folders should be installed/populated via a dependency manager at install time (`npm` and `bower`, respectively).

You should create a `.gitignore` file in the root of your project as per [this](https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files/). This should be added to git so it is cloned with the repository on other machines too.

```
# cat .gitignore
node_modules
bower_components
```

There's also a [webservice](https://www.gitignore.io/api/node,bower) to generate `.gitignore` files, that's very comprehensive. This is for `node` and `bower`:

```
# Created by https://www.gitignore.io

### Node ###
# Logs
logs
*.log

# Runtime data
pids
*.pid
*.seed

# Directory for instrumented libs generated by jscoverage/JSCover
lib-cov

# Coverage directory used by tools like istanbul
coverage

# Grunt intermediate storage (http://gruntjs.com/creating-plugins#storing-task-files)
.grunt

# node-waf configuration
.lock-wscript

# Compiled binary addons (http://nodejs.org/api/addons.html)
build/Release

# Dependency directory
# https://www.npmjs.org/doc/misc/npm-faq.html#should-i-check-my-node_modules-folder-into-git
node_modules


### Bower ###
bower_components
.bower-cache
.bower-registry
.bower-tmp
```

Comment: and what I shall do after it, GitHub doesn't see these catalog now, how to load it into github?

Comment: Can you click "Open debug log" and add the output to your question please?

Comment: what debug log, it simply show me "no changes in local directory"

Comment: and how to add output?

Comment: You will have to first "add" the files to be committed. Have you done [this](https://help.github.com/articles/synchronizing-repositories/), and is it a public repository you can share the github URL of?

Comment: sorry I'm new with GitHub)

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't commit `node_modules` nor `bower_components`. You should save your dependencies in a `package.json` and `bower.json` respectively and when cloning / checking out your project you should install your dependencies.

Add `node_modules/` and `bower_components/` to your `.gitignore` (read [here](https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files/) about editing your .gitignore) will make git "forget" that these directories exists.
This will also decrease the size of your project.

In order to create a `package.json` if you're lacking but already have installed dependencies you can use `npm shrinkwrap`.

Comment: how can I do it, is there any instractions?

Answer (score 1):

You should not have to commit `node_modules` and `bower_components`

Solution: If you already have `.gitignore` file then edit it, or if you don't have create it and edit. Add path of `node_modules` and `bower_components`. Like:

```
node_modules
bower_components
```

The way to ignore directories automatically.

Comment: ok, but now Github doesn't see this catalogs, how to load it?

Comment: This is not issue of `.gitignore`. You can restart Git UI

Comment: I restart it. nothig helps, when i delete these rows, git find that catalogs